# Android ViewPager fragment replace

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have an activity with bottom tabs, which I use to switch fragments. One of the tabs have fragment with `ViewPager` setup (with 3 tabs). `ViewPager` has a `RecyclerView` and when I click on any item, the new fragment should replace fragment in which `ViewPager` exists.
But I receive an error `No view found for id R.id.frame_layout_content for fragment  IndexFragment` when trying to replace fragment. How to properly replace fragment in this case?

Code flow:

Activity -> replace fragment in `R.id.frame_layout_content` with `ViewPagerFragment` -> Setup the `ViewPager` with fragment adapter (3 tabs) -> Click on `RecyclerView` item in `IndexFragment` to replace fragment in `R.id.frame_layout_content` with `IndexDetailsFragment`.

ViewPagerFragment:

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.pager);
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());

    adapter.addFragment(new IndexFragment(), view.getResources().getString(R.string.title_index));
    adapter.addFragment(new FaqFragment(), view.getResources().getString(R.string.title_faq));
    adapter.addFragment(new QuotesFragment(), view.getResources().getString(R.string.title_cquotes));

    mViewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

    tabLayout = (TabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
}
```

Code to change fragment from `IndexFragment`:

```
IndexDetailsFragment newFragment = new IndexDetailsFragment();
FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left);
transaction.replace(R.id.frame_layout_content, newFragment);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);
transaction.commit();
```

Comment: In which class are you calling `transaction.replace(R.id.frame_layout_content, newFragment);`?

Comment: I updated a question with few details I missed. Call above called from `IndexFragment` to replace `R.id.frame_layout_content` (which in activity) with `IndexDetailsFragment`

Answer (score 1):

Try to change

```
IndexFragment newFragment = new IndexFragment();
```

to

```
Fragment newFragment = new IndexFragment();
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Nope. It's not working. I updated a question with few details I missed.

Answer (score 1):

`R.id.frame_layout_content` is inside `MainActivity`, so `IndexFragment` won't be able to access it.

You should make an interface, so `IndexFragment` can notify `MainActivity` and then `MainActivity` should change `R.id.frame_layout_content` content.

Answer (score 0):

When I call `FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()` in `IndexFragment` (which replaced with `FragmentManager` attached to `ViewPager`) I receive an instance attached to `ViewPager` not to activity, which has `R.id.frame_layout_content`

So the solution is to get `FragmentManager` instance from parent `Activity`:

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
```